# Websocket vs SSE to implement a real time friend invitation system on React/Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, websocket

I would like to implement a system that allows users to add each other as friends and share data between them. I have gotten the authentication done and currently researching ways to do this real time. This project of mine is purely a learning experience so I am looking for many ways to perform this task to grow my knowledge.

I have experience using Websockets on a previous project and it was easy to use. Websockets seems like the best solution to my problem as it allows the user to send and receive invites through the open socket. However I have also learnt that the downside would be a long open socket connection that might be potentially performance taxing(?) Since I'm only sending/receiving information only when an invite is sent/received, websockets might be overutilized for a simple function.

At the same time I would like to learn about new technologies and I found out about Server Sent Events that would be less performance heavy(?) Using SSE would be much efficient as it only sends HTTP requests to the clients/server whenever the user send the invite.

Please correct me if I'm wrong for what I typed out above as this is what I gathered through my reading online. So now I'm having a hard time understanding whether SSE is better than websocket for my project. If there are other technologies please do let me know too! Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

how you doing ?

The best advise would be always to use websocket in this context, cuz your project can grow and need some feature that would be better using websocket

But you got another options, one of the is Firebase, Yes, FIREBASE!
You can do a nice reactive application with firebase, becouse the its observers update data in realtime, just like the websockets do.

But here go some cons and pros.

- Websocket: Can make your project escalable, its more complete, you can use it in any context, BUT: is hard to implement and takes more time to be learned and understood.
- Firebase, Easy and fast to implement, you can do a chat in 20 minuts, and surelly would help you with your problem, There is Firestore and Reatime database.. even the firestore updates in realtime..  BUT: Firebase costs in a big project can be expensive, i dont think is a good option for a big project.

Thats it.. the better options to do a real time data application to me.

A little bit more about. Firebase vs Websocket
https://ably.com/compare/firebase-vs-socketio

Answer (score 0):

to send a friend invitation, you just send an API request. WebSocket is used for real time communication.  From react.js, get the email and send the email to the server

```
export const sendFriendInvitation = async (data) => {
  try {
    return axios.post("/friend-invitation", data);
  } catch (exception) {
    console.error(error)
  }
};
```

On node.js side, write a controller to control this request:

```
const invitationRequest = async (req, res) => {
  // get the email 
  const { targetMail } = req.body;
  
  // write code to handle that same person is not sending req to himself

  // get the details of user who sent the email
  const targetUser = await User.findOne({
    mail: targetMail.toLowerCase(),
  });
  if (!targetUser) {
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send("send error message");
  }

  // you should have Invitations model
  // check if invitation already sent. 
  
  // check if the user we would like to invite is our friend
  
  // now create a new invitation
 
  // if invitation has been successfully created, update the user's friend
  
  return res.status(201).send("Invitation has been sent");
};
```